# Is this logical statement correct when the universe is the set of integers?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

∀x∃y((y > x) ∧ ∀z(((z $\ne$ y) ∧ (z > x)) ⇒ (z > y)))

I'm confused by the brackets. Right now I'm leaning towards the statement being true as it says that for all x we can find a y, and z such that the z is greater than y and x.

Comment: Hint: it does not say *we can find a $y$ and $z$*. It says *we can find a $y$ such that ... and for all $z$ ...* ! Now, try finding a suitable $y$ in terms of $x$. E.g. consider what the sentence says when you set $y=x+1$.

Comment: So, it would be true since we can indeed find a y, which is x+1 to satisfy the statement right.

Answer (score 2):

$\forall x~\exists y~\color{red}{\Big(}\color{blue}(y > x\color{blue}) \land \forall z~\color{purple}{\bigl(}\color{limegreen}(\color{pink}(z ≠ y\color{pink}) \land \color{fuchsia}(z > x\color{fuchsia})\color{limegreen}) \to \color{gold}(z > y\color{gold})\color{purple}{\bigr)}\color{red}{\Bigr)}$

"For any integer $x$ there is *some* integer $y$ that is greater than $x$, and *every* integer $z$ *will be* greater than $y$ *if it is* both not equal to $y$ and greater than $x$."

So, the claim is that: You can select *any* integer and will be able to find *some* second integer that is greater than the first *but with* **no** third integer that can be found *between* them.

Or simply "Every integer has a least greater integer."